# Manual "version tracker" for our data processing

Tags: version-control, change-tracking

We have a database system that processes data from source files into some outputs.

This "process" is continuously being updated, enhanced, cleaned and of course executed by a number of people around the company.

To keep track of who changes what, when and why we need something like a Bug tracker but not quite; more like a Version tracker which is updated manually. Something like a CHANGES file but more enhanced such as being web-based, searchable, multi-user etc. I figured that we cannot use a bugtracker such as Mantis because it's bug-driven, eg you first have to have a bug under which all is categorized. I just want changes to be logged always, no matter if there is a bug or not.

Can anyone advise me which software I could try?

Answer (score 0):

Use a Google Doc spreadsheet, shared with the group.  It's a very simple solution but offers a lot of flexibility with implementation.  Sample columns idea: issue name, logger, logged date, resolved date, status.

Comment: Hm. The columns you mention still sound like a bugtracker to me: resolved-date etc. But yes, a spreadsheet is flexible. However I'm looking for more user-friendly solutions...

Comment: Well, you don't have to have those columns.  It's just most items which are tracked have a start and end date.  Items which are simply single points in time can simply have a single date value.